# multi-tenacy Add List tenants WSO2BPS using Java

Tags: java, wso2

I want to implement a java program for adding or listing the tenants from the WSO2 Busniness Process Server. Can you help me please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add some of the code you've written so far, and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample code [1] which is written by a WSO2 guy. You have to set classpath to /server_home/repository/components/plugins folder when running the sample. You can find the related mail discussion here [2]

[1] https://github.com/arunasujith/tenant-sample

[2] https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@wso2.org/msg45614.html

Comment: Thank you for your response :) the example (add tenants to WSO2BPS) works fine !!!

Please, is there any documentations or tutorials to program with Java & WSO2BPS and to understand their basic concepts ?